# Blue on images after click firefox

Tags: jquery, css, html, firefox

Whenever I click the up carousel image it gets blue color on it.
what should I do to cancel it?
It happens on Firefox on this page:

http://michel.richkid.co.il/he/company/gallery/main/

Answer (score 5):

It is because the user is able to select the image and it is being highlighted.

To disable this use (or on a class instead of img):

```
img {
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```